# Поиск по трём таблицам

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. Такой вопрос по Delphi: есть три таблицы, на форме TTable, DataSourse, DBGrid. В каждой из таблиц, есть столбец "inv_N", и как сделать поиск, одновременно в трех таблицах по этому столбцу?

Comment: Структуру базы опишите. И что вам надо найти. Гриды подвинуть к этому инвентарному номеру или как? Что будет если такой номер есть только в одной таблице, или если таких номеров несколько? Поиск у вас жесткий или по вхождению? Нужны подробности.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрите методы JOIN: [Объяснение SQL объединений JOIN/INNER/OUTER](http://www.skillz.ru/dev/php/article-Obyasnenie_SQL_obedinenii_JOIN_INNER_OUTER.html).

Answer (score 0):

Сперва поменять TTable на TQuery или TDataSet

Потом написать SQL запрос чтото типа

```
select inv_N from table1
union
select inv_N from table2
union
select inv_N from table3
```

А там уже или можно использовать filter или locate

Хотя правильнее сделать where в запросе.

Comment: Это не сработает для множества таблиц!!!

Comment: Это какраз и на множество и сработает
JOIN обеденяет таблицы ставя поля рядом, а 
union выдает значения однотинпных полей разных таблиц друг под другом как одна таблица.

Comment: если для каждой из таблиц свой грид, то такой юнион не подойдет. тут какая-то с базой явная неоптимальность.

Comment: Ну если для каждой свой грид то 3 раза искать придется )) .
если inv_N первичный ключ проблем возникнуть не должно.

А если нет то надо подумать с сторону оптимизации базы.